# How to suppress showing the whole current fold path in Windows terminal so that it will get as in Linux?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

When you work in the Windows terminal, you see your full current fold path on the left. I would like to make it looking like in Linux where only the last directory name is shown, becasuse my current working folds are too deep & paths demands more than a half of screen. I tried to google this through a lot of phrases but it led to nothing. I suppose the problem is in the mismatch of my English lexicon with a native user's.

*windows show the last path as in linux, windows not show whole path, powershell show not all directory path* &c. gave me nothing useful or relevant. Is there a way to set **cmd** to suppress showing the full path?

Comment: If you wanted to use [Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) rather than cmd.exe, there are [many possibilities for customisation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/custom-prompt-setup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **PowerShell**, `Prompt` is by default, a built-in function that returns a string. In a **PowerShell** session where the prompt hasn't been customized, the underlying code can be viewed by typing:

- `(Get-Command prompt).ScriptBLock`

  ```
   PS C:\>
   >> "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel +
   >> 1)) ";
   >> # .Link
   >> # https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
   >> # .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
   >>
   >>
  ```

You can use this code as the basis for a custom function that will override the default.

In the above, the path is obtained by this code:

- `$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)`

To pare it down to the current directory name, change it to:

- `$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path.Split('\')[-1])`

So to override the default prompt, declare  a function of the same mane:

```
function Prompt {
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path.Split('\')[-1])$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel +1)) "
}
```

To make the custom prompt the default for new sessions, add the function definition to your **PowerShell** profile. The following code will add it to your existing profile, or create your profile if you don't have one.

```
If (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE )) {
    New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force | out-null }
@'
function Prompt {
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path.Split('\')[-1])$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel +1)) "
}
'@ | Add-Content -Path $PROFILE -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `prompt` sets the starting text of the windows terminal. Its options are shown here:

| **Zeichen** | **Beschreibung** |
| --- | --- |
| $q | = (Equal sign) |
| $$ | $ (Dollar sign) |
| $t | Current time |
| $d | Current date |
| $p | Current drive and path |
| $v | Windows version number |
| $n | Current drive |
| $g | > (Greater than sign) |
| $l | < (Less than sign) |
| $b | | (Pipe symbol) |
| $_ | ENTER-LINEFEED |
| $e | ANSI escape code (code 27) |
| $h | Backspace (to delete a character that has been written to the command line) |
| $a | & (Ampersand) |
| $c | ( (Left parenthesis) |
| $f | ) (Right parenthesis) |
| $s | Space |

From: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt

As you can see it does not list any option to set the start text to the current folder. To get more space you can change it to only show something like ">" with:

```
prompt $G
```

This was already answered in: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466980/change-windows-command-prompt-to-show-only-current-folder)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that this is called prompt. I prefer to avoid workarounds with `prompt` command, because this does not look trusty. I thought that this is somewhere in settings.

Comment: Please could you [edit] and quote the relevant part of the link in your answer, in case of [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Otherwise your answer is almost a link-only answer.

Comment: You are right. I expanded the answer.